# Angular tab selecting using controller method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-class, angularjs-controlleras

I am trying to use AngularJS to display the tab number when certain tab is selected using the controller method.  It does not as expected.  Greatly appreciate your help on this one.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="coolApp">
    <section ng-controller="panelSelector as panel">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSet(1)}"><a href ng-click="panel.setTab(1)">Concert Band</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSet(2)}"><a href ng-click="panel.setTab(2)">Ceremonial Band</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSet(3)}"><a href ng-click="panel.setTab(3)">191st Jazz Combo</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSet(4)}"><a href ng-click="panel.setTab(4)">Brass Ensemble</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSet(5)}"><a href ng-click="panel.setTab(5)">Celtic Fire</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p> the tab number is: {{tab}}</p>
    </section>
</body>
```

**Code**

```
var app = angular.module("coolApp", []);
app.controller("panelSelector", function(){
this.tab = 1; 

this.setTab = function(tabChoice){
    this.tab = tabChoice;
};
this.isSet = function(checkTab){
    return this.tab = checkTab;
};
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module("coolApp", []);
app.controller("panelSelector", function(){
  var panel = this;
  panel.tab = 1; 

  panel.setTab = function(tabChoice){
      panel.tab = tabChoice;
  };
  panel.isSet = function(checkTab){
      return panel.tab == checkTab;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="coolApp">
<section ng-controller="panelSelector as panel">
            <ul class = "nav nav-pills">
                <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSet(1)}"><a href ng-click = "panel.setTab(1)">Concert Band</a></li>
                <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSet(2)}"><a href ng-click = "panel.setTab(2)">Ceremonial Band</a></li>
                <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSet(3)}"><a href ng-click = "panel.setTab(3)">191st Jazz Combo</a></li>
                <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSet(4)}"><a href ng-click = "panel.setTab(4)">Brass Ensemble</a></li>
                <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSet(5)}"><a href ng-click = "panel.setTab(5)">Celtic Fire</a></li>
            </ul>
            <p> the tab number is: {{panel.tab}}</p>
</section>
</body>
```

- Your reference to `panel` with `this` was not correct,
- You were using `{{tab}}` instead of `{{panel.tab}}` to display the selected tab,
- And your return statement should have been `return panel.tab == checkTab;`.

Hope the issue is resolved!

Answer (score 1):

Your `this` inside a `setTab` & `isSet` function are different, you should have declare a variable and assign `this`.

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module("coolApp", []);
app.controller("panelSelector", function(){
  var panel = this;
  panel.tab = 1; 

  panel.setTab = function(tabChoice){
      panel.tab = tabChoice;
  };
  panel.isSet = function(checkTab){
      return panel.tab == checkTab;
  };
});
```

Comment: So at the end of the this function, we have a `return`, and you changed it to `panel.tab == checkTab;`.  Does this mean that it will return true when any tab is clicked since the ng-click and ng-class's parameter entered for each tab is equal?

Comment: @MingHuang yes it will return a bool based on there both condition.